# Heroku, php, exec and telegram bot

Tags: php, heroku, exec, telegram

I have created a telegram bot and I would like to be able to make the index.php execute another php (worker.php) in background using exec command when the telegram bot receives a particular message from the user.
If possible, I'd like to do it in a simpler way comparing to that of the [Heroku example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-workers).
The worker.php code should be able to send a message to the telegram chat too, as the index.php is doing at the moment.
I have then set this example to check the argument pass (particularly the chat information), but it's not. This is the code, could anybody please help? At the moment is not really running in background as the /dev/null & commands are not set in the "exec" command.

On the "sender" side:

```
$update_j = json_encode($update);

$response = $client->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id,
            'text' => $update_j
]);

exec('php /app/worker.php?update=' . $update_j, $out, $ret_v);
```

The output of $update_j looks correct:

```
{"update_id":XXXXXXXXX,"message":{"message_id":YYYY,"from":{"id":ZZZZZZZZ,"first_name":"Name"},"chat":{"id":ZZZZZZZZ,"first_name":"Name","type":"private"},"date":WWWWWWWWWWW,"text":"\/runjob","entities":[{"type":"bot_command","offset":0,"length":7}]}}
```

On the worker.php side, the code is this:

```
<?php


require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'require.php';


try {

$foo = file_get_contents("php://input");
$out = json_decode($foo, true);
$update = $out->{'update'};

$response = $client->sendChatAction(['chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id, 'action' => 'typing']);
$response = $client->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id,
            'text' => "var_dump = " . var_dump($out)
]);


} catch (\Zelenin\Telegram\Bot\NotOkException $e) {}
```

The value of $ret_v is 1. I don't get any message containing var_dump($out) value.

Can somebody help on what's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you now `text` in [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) should be a string

So you could use `json_encode`instead of `var_dump()`

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) :

> string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth =
>   512 ]] )
>   Returns a string containing the JSON representation of
>   value.

update for your code:

```
$response = $client->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id,
            'text' => "var_dump = " . json_encode($out)
]);
```